# Docker compose with nginx keeps displaying welcome page

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm new to *docker* and trying the simplest docker-compose.yml showing an hello world page to build on top of that with eventually a full *LEMP stack* that would have the same config as my server. However most tutorials are obsolete and there are so many ways of using *docker* that I can't find one using only *Docker compose* v3 that is still actual. I checked the docs and it's awfully confusing as well for a beginner, been trying to make it work for the past 5 hours so I thought I'd ask on SO.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.10.3-r0 #using this version as it's the same on my server
    volumes:
      - "./test.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.local"
      - "./test.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.local"
      - "./code:/var/www/html" #code contains only a basic index.html file
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

**test.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.local;

    index index.html; #Only a basic helloworld index.html file
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;
}
```

Do I need a *Dockerfile* with this? Tutorials don't seem to mention it's needed.

**NOTE:**
Tried adding the volume

```
- "./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
```

but nothing changes and the welcome page still loads, while with *nginx:latest* I get a very verbose error containing this phrase: "unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type".

**UPDATE about docker-compose.yml:**

- Without the line `"./code:/usr/share/nginx/html"`, the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder contains the default index.html file (expected)
- With the line `"./code:/usr/share/nginx/html"`, the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder is **EMPTY**!
- With the line `"./:/usr/share/nginx/html"`, the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder has and empty "code" folder and a bunch of random test files I deleted a while ago.

Between tries, I run my reset script to make sure I start fresh:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q) --force
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

Running `docker inspect <container>` returns this for the volume, not sure it's normal that the type is "bind" for as a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) instead of a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/e/DEV/sandbox/docker",
        "Destination": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
        "Mode": "rw",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but i think the problem is, that the default configuration takes configs from the location "/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf"

Comment: Thanks friend, I had already tried to overwrite that file but it won't work. I added some more details in my question

Comment: In the sites-enabled folder you are mounting the virtual host config file as `test.local`. Try giving it a name that ends with `.conf`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, no luck however..

Comment: in your docker-compose.yml the volumes are in pairs the_left_side:its_right_side  notice the full colon delimiter the directory on left side must exist local to host where you launch the container the directory on right side gets mounted to that local dir as viewed from inside the new container so they point to same place

Comment: @ScottStensland yes I'm aware of that thanks :) The update I just added is to show how weird the behavior is. The first result is expected, but the second and third don't make any sense. It looks like my docker is corrupt but it's a fresh install

Comment: I will write a new question as this is clearly not an nginx image issue as it is more a volume issue and will see later what to do with the current question

Comment: Same issues. Identical. Any news about?

Comment: Nope, nothing yet

Comment: ended with same problem...

Answer (score 30):

It's  easy to mount your own hello world page. I'll explain it using the official `nginx:latest` image but you can do it for yourself with the bitnami image if you want.

First the very basic. Just run the nginx container (without docker-compose). I'll explain it in detail and basic, of course I can try to perform more advanced or faster commands to read files which are inside the container but this can be confusing for a beginner. So just run the container and name it `my-nginx`:

```
$ docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 --name my-nginx nginx
```

Go to `localhost:80`, you'll see the default nginx page.
Now you can exec inside the container by using it's name. exec will bring you 'inside the container' so you can check its files.

```
$ docker exec -it my-nginx bash
root@2888fdb672a1:/# cd /etc/nginx/
root@2888fdb672a1:/etc/nginx# ls
conf.d      koi-utf  mime.types  nginx.conf   uwsgi_params
fastcgi_params  koi-win  modules     scgi_params  win-utf
```

Now read the `nginx.conf` by using `cat`.
The most important line in this file is:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

This means all the `confs` inside that directory are used/read.
So go into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.

```
root@2888fdb672a1:~# cd /etc/nginx/conf.d/
root@2888fdb672a1:/etc/nginx/conf.d# ls
default.conf
```

The `default.conf` is the only file. Inside this file you see the configuration:

```
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

server is local host, port is 80 and the file that will be displayed is in the directory `/usr/share/nginx/html/`

Now check that file in your container:

```
root@2888fdb672a1:/etc/nginx/conf.d# cat /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
...
```

It's the expected file. It's the 'Welcome to Nginx' page we can see.
So how can we show our own `index.html`? By just mounting it in `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

You'll `docker-compose.yaml` will look like this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

The code directory just contains an `index.html` with hello world.
Run `docker-compose up -d --build` and when you curl `localhost:80` you will see your own `index.html`.

If you really want to put your code in `/var/www/html` instead of `/usr/share/nginx` you can do that.

Use your `test.conf`. Here you define to put your file in `/var/www/html/`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.local;

    index index.html; #Only a basic helloworld index.html file
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;
}
```

In the compose you will overwrite the `default.conf` with your own conf where you tell nginx to look in `/var/www/html`. 
Your compose can look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - "./test.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./code:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Now you will also see your own `index.html` while it's on your own specified location. Long answer but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that super detailed answer! I already knew most of it but I still tried. Unfortunately the default message is still showing. I discovered something very strange however, check out the latest update in my question, I'm really confused

Comment: Can you make a directory code with just the index file and mount it like this: ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html and use docker-compose up --build to surely rebuild your image., Be sure your local environment is clean too

Comment: Just tried with --build, same result as in my question.. the html folder is empty on the container. I run these commands between trials to clean up everything and it still changes nothing: "docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)", "docker rmi $(docker images -q) --force", "docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)"

Comment: I think my doker might be corrupt, but it's a fresh installation so I don't get it and don't know where to ask

Comment: can you try this?:: docker-compose rm --all && docker-compose pull &&
docker-compose build --no-cache &&
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate &&

Comment: Still the same result, even tried running from a different local folder just in case, thanks for all these useful commands I didn't know however! It really seems something is wrong with my environment. I filed a bug report on github and wrote to docker support about it.

Comment: I think I will delete this question and write a new one with the specific volumes issue. Or it might be better to leave it since your answer has a lot of useful info actually

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper, There appears to be some sort of precedence issue. The NGINX welcome "index.html" file is not being replaced/superseded by the volume mapping of Docker. Any other files can be browsed to... Just not if they are called index.html.

So a work-around would be to simply remove "index.html" from the site.conf as a default, and put some other default in it's place.

I tested this and it works... If you can bear the lameness of it.

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper Any luck my friend, I am also facing the same issue ...

Comment: @user3457622 That was 2 years ago, the solution didn't work for me and I have not worked with Docker since so I don't have the answer

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a lot on this question, I have figured out three factors that made my deploy with docker-compose work.
I did a website in nodejs.

## We expose web part and nginx on port 80

---

Dockerfile for nodejs : **[ important line is -> EXPOSE 80 ]**

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /
COPY package.json ./
EXPOSE 80

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "bin/www"]
```

Nginx.conf for nginx : **[ important line is -> listen 80; ]**

```
events {

}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
    }
  }
}
```

## We give to nginx config file, the name and port of web's image

---

docker-compose.yaml :
**[ important line is -> image: nodejs ]** that is the name of web's image
AND
**[ important line is -> ports: -"3000:3000" ]** that is the port to run web's part

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  webserver:
    image: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Nginx.conf for nginx : **[ important line is -> proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000; ]**

```
events {

}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
    }
  }
}
```

## We give nginx's image, volumes as path for the config file to replace default one

---

Tree :

```
mainfolder
.
|_____nginx
|  |______nginx.conf
|
|_____Dockerfile
|
|_____docker-compose.yaml
```

docker-compose.yaml : 
**[ important line is -> ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ]** to replace config file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  webserver:
    image: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```