# Docker compose with nginx keeps displaying welcome to nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a wordpress environment using docker-compose and nginx. The thing is that I can't make nginx use wordpress index.php, even though I overrode the default.conf and mounted my wordpress file structure to /var/www/html.

Here is the relevant part of the yml file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  wordpress:

services:
  site:
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

Here I'm mounting the `wordpress` folder to the `/var/www/html` folder that I'm creating with my nginx.dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

ADD ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
```

And here is my default.conf file:

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
    server php:9000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8443;
    listen [::]:8443;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

**What I tested:**

[Someone on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705838/docker-compose-with-nginx-keeps-displaying-welcome-page) had the same exact issue, and the answer seems pretty clear but unfortunately it didn't work.

When running `docker-compose run --rm site cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` it prints my default.conf file, and I also confirm that my wordpress structure with the index.php is in the folder /var/www/html.

I also tested to rename config files, deleting the cache of docker and rebuilding everything from scratch, but nginx doesn't care and loads it's own config file.

[Some people on Github](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/419) recommended to change the php container name to something like php-box1 to avoid confusion but it didn't help either.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you placing the nginx config file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled ?

Comment: No I'm overring `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Firstly, if the welcome message was still showing up is because of the browser's cache. After clearing the cache I was getting an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. The problem was within the `docker-compose.yml` file, to bind the 8080 port to 80 I wrote `8080:80` instead of `80:8080`. I hope it will help someone out there.